# How to parse xml in XMPPMessage to swift?

Tags: ios, xml, swift, xml-parsing, xmppframework

Here is my code in swift.

```
func xmppStream(sender: XMPPStream!, didReceiveMessage message: XMPPMessage!) {
   print( message.prettyXMLString())
}
```

Receive  message format is :

```
 <message xmlns="jabber:client" from="pubsub.myanmarnet.com" to="001026992@myanmarnet.com" type="headline">
      <event xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event">
        <items type="headline" node="mynet.global">
          <item id="1474017969">
            <xml>
              <title>Myanmar Net</title>
              <about>Hi,Good Evening!!!</about>
              <published>2016-09-16 15:56:09</published>
            </xml>
          </item>
        </items>
      </event>
      <delay xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" from="admin@myanmarnet.com/jaxl#cf05ff5e6c92663a32a997f0ea4cf543" stamp="2016-09-16T09:26:09Z"/>
    </message>
```

I want to retrieve and display (Hi,Good Evening!!!)  in table view with swift.

Comment: Isn't the `message` the parsed state already? You want to convert it to XML and then again parse the XML? :-)

Comment: I want these XML format <title>,<about>,<published> to swift and display in swift. @hnh

Comment: I got this answer. I used xmlparser pod lib.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a PubSub Message as defined in [XEP-60](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html). If you're using the XMMPFramework by Robbie Hanson, [it comes with the XEP-60 extension](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/blob/master/Extensions/XEP-0060/XMPPPubSub.h). You don't have to deal with the parsing.